# The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here is a code written inside the build of the "home.dart" file. The file is opened when there is a login or a registration happened and is currently logged in.

```
return StreamProvider<QuerySnapshot>.value(
      initialData:{'sugars':0,'name':"new user","strength":100},
      value: DatabaseService(uid: '').brews,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Home Screen"),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton.icon(onPressed: ()async{
            print("clicked here");
            await _auth.signOut(); 
          }, icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: Text("Logout")),
        ],),
        body: BrewList(),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: please add more code

Comment: Your `StreamProvider` as `QuerySnapshot` type and inside the initialData you are passing a `Map`, try removing the initialData or changing to a QuerySnapshot.

Comment: That sounds like the start of a good answer @LucasJosino :-)

Comment: How to write that in the form of QuerySnapshot instead of Map?